# Generating a Flicking carousel with React leads to the getComputedStyle error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getcomputedstyle

This question is about [egjs-flicking](https://naver.github.io/egjs-flicking/) library but perhaps problem is more general.

Let us consider two examples of components that will differ only by their `render()` method. First I provide the whole component.

```js
import React from 'react';

import Flicking, { MoveEvent, FlickingError } from "@egjs/react-flicking";

class Credits extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.readtime = 1000;
        this.maxElements = 4;
        this.actionReady = this.actionReady.bind(this);
        this.actionReset = this.actionReset.bind(this);
        this.actionMove = this.actionMove.bind(this);
        this.processFlicking = this.processFlicking.bind(this);
    }

    async actionReady(e) {
        const status = e.currentTarget.getStatus();
        setTimeout(() => {
            e.currentTarget.moveTo(status.position.panel + 1);
        }, this.readTime);
    }

    async actionReset(e, delay) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            e.currentTarget.moveTo(0);
        }, delay);
    }

    async actionMove(e) {
        const status = e.currentTarget.getStatus();
        setTimeout(() => {
            e.currentTarget.moveTo(status.position.panel + 1);
        }, this.readTime);
    }

    async processFlicking(e) {
        const status = e.currentTarget.getStatus();
        const remaining = status.panels.length - status.position.panel;
        if (remaining == this.maxElements) {
            this.actionReset(e, this.readtime*this.maxElements);
        } else {
            this.actionMove(e);
        }
    }

    getMStyle() {
        return {
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        };
    }

    render() {
        // this is where the examples differ
    }
}
```

### Static case

Now the first case is the children of the `Flicking` container are pre-defined.

```js
render() {
        const PanelComponent = this.props.panelComponent;
        return (
            <Flicking
              style={this.getMStyle()}
              circular={false}
              align={"prev"}
              horizontal={false}
              onReady={this.actionReady}
              onMoveEnd={this.processFlicking}
            >
              <div>hello</div><div>sup</div><div>how are u</div><div>cze</div><div>konnichiwa</div><div>salam</div><div>namaste</div>
            </Flicking>
        );
    }
```

which gives the following rendered HTML

```html
<div class="flicking-camera">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>sup</div>
  <div>how are u</div>
  <div>cze</div>
  <div>konnichiwa</div>
  <div>salam</div>
  <div>namaste</div>
</div>
```

### Dynamic case

Here they are generated dynamically

```js
render() {
        const PanelComponent = this.props.panelComponent;
        return (
            <Flicking
              style={this.getMStyle()}
              circular={false}
              align={"prev"}
              horizontal={false}
              onReady={this.actionReady}
              onMoveEnd={this.processFlicking}
            >
              { this.props.panels.map((data, index) =>
                  ( <PanelComponent key={index} data={data.content} /> )) }
            </Flicking>
        );
    }
```

giving the following rendered HTML (identical to previous)

```html
<div class="flicking-camera">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>sup</div>
  <div>how are u</div>
  <div>cze</div>
  <div>konnichiwa</div>
  <div>salam</div>
  <div>namaste</div>
</div>
```

for PanelComponent it was using

```js
class EntryElement extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{ this.props.data }</div>
        )
    }
}
```

to generate each of the panels.

### Problem

The static case works perfectly, the dynamic case gives the following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at getStyle (utils.ts:259:1)
    at Panel.__proto.resize (Panel.ts:323:1)
    at Renderer.ts:163:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ReactRenderer.__proto.updatePanelSize (Renderer.ts:163:1)
    at Flicking.<anonymous> (Flicking.ts:1227:1)
    at step (index.ts:1:1)
    at Object.next (index.ts:1:1)
    at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)
```

and I am really puzzled why because resulting HTML is identical... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I actually found it. All thanks to [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/naver/egjs-flicking/issues/485) and [here](https://github.com/naver/egjs-flicking/issues/485#issuecomment-1084727810) is my relevant comment.

From https://naver.github.io/egjs-flicking/docs/quick-start I checked section `Bypassing ref forwarding` and added `useFindDOMNode={true}` to my Flicking.

Here is the complete working source that is able to dynamically put children components in Flicking

```js
class Credits extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.readtime = 1000;
        this.maxElements = 4;
        this.actionReady = this.actionReady.bind(this);
        this.actionReset = this.actionReset.bind(this);
        this.actionMove = this.actionMove.bind(this);
        this.processFlicking = this.processFlicking.bind(this);
        this.createPanel = this.createPanel.bind(this);
    }

    async actionReady(e) {
        const status = e.currentTarget.getStatus();
        setTimeout(() => {
            e.currentTarget.moveTo(status.position.panel + 1);
        }, this.readTime);
    }

    async actionReset(e, delay) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            e.currentTarget.moveTo(0);
        }, delay);
    }

    async actionMove(e) {
        const status = e.currentTarget.getStatus();
        setTimeout(() => {
            e.currentTarget.moveTo(status.position.panel + 1);
        }, this.readTime);
    }

    async processFlicking(e) {
        const status = e.currentTarget.getStatus();
        const remaining = status.panels.length - status.position.panel;
        if (remaining == this.maxElements) {
            this.actionReset(e, this.readtime*this.maxElements);
        } else {
            this.actionMove(e);
        }
    }

    getMStyle() {
        return {
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        };
    }

    createPanel(panel, index) {
        const PanelComponent = this.props.panelComponent;
        return <PanelComponent data={panel.content} key={index} />;
    }

    createPanels(panels) {
        return panels.map(this.createPanel);
    }

    render() {
        const panels = this.props.panels;
        return (
            <Flicking
              useFindDOMNode={true}
              style={this.getMStyle()}
              circular={false}
              align={"prev"}
              horizontal={false}
              onReady={this.actionReady}
              onMoveEnd={this.processFlicking}
            >
              { this.createPanels(panels) }
            </Flicking>
        );
    }
}
```